# How to get folder history in perforce using the command line?

Tags: command-line, perforce

`p4 filelog filename` gives me the full history of a file.

I want to get the full history of a folder.

I tried `p4 filelog foldername`, but it didn't work.  I referred to the Perforce command line [manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/) as well, but I couldn't find anything.

Here 'filename' stands for the full path to a file and 'foldername' stands for the full path to a folder.

Comment: `p4 filelog /path/to/folder/...`

Comment: sorry for not clarifying. Foldername means path to folder

Comment: Did you notice the syntax mentioned above?  `p4 filelog foldername/...` (observe the trailing `/...`)

Comment: @devnull, can you post that as an answer? Seems spot-on to me.

Comment: I must be missing something. append `/...` to the folder path just lists the history of every file in the path, recursively. Not what I or the OP was asking for.

Comment: @BillDoor It may not be what you expected, but I believe that it is the answer, as Perforce does not recognize directories as archivable objects, to the best of my understanding.  Watch this space for more experienced commentary (hopefully).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I'm looking to get folder history I tend to run `p4 changes /some/interesting/folder/...` to see a list of all the changes that have occurred. Then I use 'p4 describe ' to inspect individual changes.

Comment: Emphasis on three dots after the last `/`.

Comment: What is the meaning of that three dots?
`...`